# Merging a list of maps into one map in R

Tags: r, merge, montecarlo, r-sf

I created a list 50 Monte Carlo Simulations of some points within their radius of uncertainty (acc.)
How can I merge all these maps into one map that contains all the created points?

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

#creating points
mydf <- structure(list(x = c(555624,
                             572481,
                             703318,
                             700818, 
                             571713,
                             559113,
                             731606,
                             604972),
                       y = c(218959,
                             184051,
                             233180,
                             233603,
                             182307,
                             153136,
                             279015,
                             200216),
                      acc.=c(120.35451,
                             128.74603,
                             74.63894,
                             73.96213,
                             93.63799,
                             257.49205,
                             53.59192,
                             190.78791)),
                      .Names = c("x","y","acc."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
mydf = st_as_sf(mydf, coords=c("x","y"), crs=21781)

n = 50 #how many iterations?

point <- mydf$geometry
maxdist <- mydf$acc.

#MC Simulation
move_point <- function(point, maxdistance){
  
  n_points <- length(point)
  
  angle_deg <- runif(n_points,1,360)
  
  distance <- rnorm(n_points,mean = 0,sd = maxdistance/2)
  
  angle_rad <- (angle_deg * pi) / (180)
  
  point_old <- st_coordinates(point)
  
  xoffset <- cos(angle_rad) * distance
  yoffset <- sin(angle_rad) * distance
  
  point_new <- point_old + matrix(c(xoffset,yoffset), ncol = 2)
  
  point_new <- point_new %>%
    split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
    map(~st_point(.x))%>%
    st_sfc()
  
  point_new
}

#create a list of all MC Simulations
monte <- purrr::map(1:n, function(x){
  at <-move_point(mydf$geometry, mydf$acc.)  #assigns the move_point function to at
  at <- st_as_sf(at, crs=21781)     #assigns all the list-points a projection
})
monte    ##shows all the created maps

#now what i try to do 
merge(monte) #or
merge(monte[[1:50]])
```

I also have another list where I calculated the KDE of every iteration of the MC Simulations, of which I want to know the mean value of all the maps I have.

Edit: I could solve the first problem by using purrr::map_dfr(), but I still could not merge multiple raster files.

Comment: Would `stack()` from the `raster` package help? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/1.0.0-1/topics/stack

Comment: @EugeneChong I solved it now by using brick() from the raster package :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `do.call("rbind",monte)`